# Async series responds with false, when it should be true

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey so I am using an async series to create an array with the user found in a search result to loop through and see if they are part of the friend request array of the user logged in. However, for some reason it is always ending up as false, does anyone notice anything wrong with the code below?

Here is the code for the route file:

```
exports.searchPost = function(req, res, err) {
    User.find({$or:[
            {firstName: req.body.firstName},
            {lastName: req.body.lastName},
            {email: req.body.email},
            {phone: req.body.phone}]
    }, function(err, users, userAdd) {
        if(err) {

            return res.render('searchError', {title: 'Weblio'}); 
        } else {

            if(req.body.firstName=== '' && req.body.lastName==='' && req.body.email==='' && req.body.phone=== '') {
                //maybe  a diff page saying that is not a valid search page
                return res.render('searchError', {title: 'Weblio'});        
            } else {


                    var userAdd,
                    series = [];

                    console.log('addman');
                    users.forEach(function (user) {
                        series.push(function (callback) {
                            User.findById(req.signedCookies.userid, {
                                friendRequest: user._id
                            }, function () {
                                if (user._id === true) {
                                console.log('addman1');
                                return callback(null, [user, true]);
                                } else {
                                    console.log('addman2');
                                    console.log(user._id);
                                    return callback(null, [user, false]);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });

                async.series(series, function (err, results) {
                //results should be an in order array of values;
                console.log(results);
            return res.render('searchResults', {title: 'Weblio',         
                    userAdded: results
                });
            }); 

            }

        }
    });

};
```

Comment: BTW, you can replace `forEach()` / `push()` with `map()`.

Comment: Would it change the wrong output though, for some reason I just keep getting false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a couple of issues where you check `if (user._id === true) {`.

The first issue is that your expecting `user._id` to be a Boolean - which it probably isn't. A simple `if (user._id) {` will check if it's a "[truthy](http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/07/advanced-javascript-operators-and-truthy-falsy/)" value - which all numbers except 0 are.

However, I think there may be a second issue there: that `user` variable is from your `users.forEach(function (user) {` - I'm guessing that you actually want to be checking the results of your `User.findById(req.signedCookies.userid, {friendRequest: user._id} function(...` code. In that case you need to add `error, user2` parameters to the callback function or something along those lines.

Comment: user2 like this User.findById(req.signedCookies.userid, {
                                friendRequest: user._id
                            }, function (user2) {  Or are you referring to replacing the user in the callback function to user2?

Comment: Just like you said, `function(user2) {` and then `if (user2._id) { ...`

Comment: getting TypeError cannot read property '_id' of null for that line of if (user2._id) {

Comment: Before the `if` statement, call `console.dir(arguments)` - that should tell you what you're working with. I think the first arg is actually for errors and the second is the data. Sorry about that, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ok I understand that, and that is correct but what is the second argument, how do I call the data I queried?

Comment: What db library are you using? (Run `npm ls` from the project directory.)  And what's your overall goal with this code?

Comment: Hey thanks nathan but I figured it out, using a much simpler method even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815251/loop-is-not-outputting-true-or-false-based-on-query